# sql query for count unique values and return single row

Tags: mysql, sql

here is the structure of my table with data

```
empId, acitve

1,1

2,0

3,1

45,0

52,1

11,1
```

1. I want to know all members count [result is 6]
2. I want to know active member count (active=1) [result is 4]
3. I want to know non-active member count (active=0) [result is 2]

But all data should be return in a single row with appropriate column name.

I tried this but its result is not according the expectations:

```
SELECT Count(*) total, active as total
FROM it_staff_status
GROUP by active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
select Count(*) total,
       sum(active=1) as activemem,
       sum(active=0) as inactivemem
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

**TRY THIS:** User `CASE` to count `active` & `inactive` and you don't need `group by` here because all the columns are aggregated by using aggregate function:

```
SELECT Count(*) total, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACTIVE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Active,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACTIVE = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as InActive
FROM it_staff_status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
SUM(CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN 1 END) as active_emp,
SUM(CASE WHEN active = 0 THEN 1 END) as inactive_emp
FROM it_staff_status
```